# Is this OleDbDataAdapter bug

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, oledb

It doesn't look to me OleDbDataAdapter should throw an exception on trying to fill DataSet for a db table column of type decimal(28,3). The message is "The numerical value is too large to fit into a 96 bit decimal".
Could you just check this, I have no significant experience with ADO.NET and OLE DB components?

The VB.NET code we have in the application is this:

```
Dim dbDataSet As New DataSet
Dim dbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
Dim conn As OleDbConnection
Dim connectionString As String

'parts where connectionString is set 

conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

'part where sqlQuery is set but it ends up being "SELECT Price As 'Price' From PricebookView" - Price is of type decimal(28,3)

dbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn)
dbCommand.CommandTimeout = cmdTimeout
dbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand)
dbDataAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet)
```

The last line is where the exception is thrown and the top of the stack trace is:

```
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbBuffer.ReadNumeric(Int32 offset)     
at System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.Value_NUMERIC()     
at System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.Value()     
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)     
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)     
at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()     
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)     
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)     
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)     
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)     
...
```

I am not sure why does it try to set the value to Int32.

Thank you for the time !

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `decimal(28,3)` is capable of producing numbers that need more than 96 bits to store.

Comment: me too.and we have some with 28 digits.but do you know why OleDbDataReader tries to store it in an integer(int32) from the stack top,and not some decimal type?

Comment: @Срба you mean `DbBuffer.ReadNumeric(Int32 Offset)`? That returns a decimal, the parameter is just the byte offset.

Comment: Ok, then it looks all is fine with .NET components and this is just an error in our system architecture. As soon as data having 25 digits left of the decimal point appeared the app started crashing. The conclusion is we should have set smaller scope for the sql decimal column in order to be able to read it? thanks